# Inverse of STRING_ESCAPE() in T-SQL for escaped JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, escaping

I have some unfortunately malformed JSON, where the inner JSON object (the output value) is ESCAPED, and prevents being read properly.

Example:

```
DECLARE @jsonContent nvarchar(max) = '{"output":"{\n\"latest_activity\": \"2021-12-04T08:32:19.343228\"\n}"}'
```

SQL server does not seem to like this - the below returns NULL

```
  SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonContent, '$.output.latest_activity') AS latest_activity
```

However, the following gets the desired result, by replacing the escaped double quotes with just double quotes:

```
  SELECT CAST(
            JSON_VALUE(
                REPLACE(
                    JSON_VALUE(@jsonContent, '$.output')
                    , '\"', '')
                , '$.latest_activity')
            AS datetime2(7))
        AS [latest_activity]
```

Is there a better way to get this done, and handle other escaped characters?

I was hoping for the opposite of the built-in STRING_ESCAPE function, but alas does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON isn't malformed as such, it is just stringified JSON. You need to get the `output` property with `JSON_VALUE`, then use `JSON_VALUE` again.

```sql
DECLARE @jsonContent nvarchar(max) = '{"output":"{\n\"latest_activity\": \"2021-12-04T08:32:19.343228\"\n}"}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(@jsonContent, '$.output'), '$.latest_activity');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2be2c545c3b221f5f8acd9c24b67ec16)

Comment: I meant malformed in the sense that only the value for output is "escaped" and not the whole JSON, but now I do see in fact the entire value is quoted and is actually stringified to your point. Don't code tired. Thanks for the answer.